# Salvar array bi-dimensional na memória EEPROM

Tags: c++, array, arduino, array-multidimensional

Estou fazendo um programa para o Arduino escrito em C++ para ligar e desligar leds quando um botão é pressionado.
Quero salvar em uma memória EEPROM os valores dos leds que estiverem ligados e a quantidade de luminosidade.

Pensei em usar um array, sendo assim o primeiro elemento seria a referência para o objeto especifico e o segundo o quantidade de luminosidade. Ainda sou novo em programação em geral, dei uma pesquisada e acabei pensando tentando utilizar um array bi-dimensional, que acabou não funcionando perfeitamente.

Comment: Sua pergunta nao contem uma pergunta XD Seja mais especifico. E e sempre bom colocar o que vc ja fez.

Answer (score 3):

O [`EEPROM`](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/EEPROM) tem apenas duas funções para ler ou escrever **bytes**. Então você obrigatóriamente tem que fazer a leitura/escrita dos seus dados byte a byte.

Pode usar algo assim:

```
void EEPROM_writeMany(unsigned addressOffset, char* array, unsigned size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        EEPROM.write(addressOffset+i, array[i]);
}

int data[] = {54, 87, 21, -5, 0};

EEPROM_writeMany(0, (char*)data, sizeof(data));
```

Para fazer a leitura, basta criar uma função análoga usando `EEPROM.read`.